# Multi-Level Component Callbacks in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I am coming from a React / Redux mindset where data-manipulation functions as well as data are passed from parent to child to grandchild etc. Components themselves do not modify data, rather they pass their intentions back up the component tree.

I am trying to replicate this with components in Angular 1.5. Consider the following:

`app.js`:

```
const appController = ($scope, data) => {
  $scope.doSomething = () => console.log('Foooooo!');
};
```

`app.html`:

```
<div>
  <node
    do-something="doSomething()"
  ></node>
</div>
```

`node.js`:

```
app.component('node', {
  // ...
  bindings: {
    doSomething: '&',
  },
});
```

`node.html`:

```
<div>
  <leaf
    do-something="$ctrl.doSomething()"
  ></leaf>
</div>
```

`leaf.js`:

```
app.component('leaf', {
  // ...
  bindings: {
    doSomething: '&',
  },
});
```

`leaf.html`:

```
<div ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()"></div>
```

This works. When the `div` in `leaf` is clicked `'Foooooo!'` is logged to the console. However, if I change the `ngClick` callback to pass in something in scope for `leaf` (or even just a literal such as `'foo'`) and change `doSomething` in `app.js` to take an argument that argument is `undefined`. My guess is that I have to somehow pass the data along in `node`, but I don't know how. Is there a way to pass arguments along intermediary components without having to write wrapper functions in scope? I've tried using `arguments` but that doesn't work -- is there some Angular way to accomplish what I want?

**EDIT:**

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7L4Kd3rhJXoGlrHzecHf?p=preview

Comment: lol, node.js. That could get confusing. Also, a plunkr would be nice.

Comment: Try making your binding a reference instead of an expression, so instead of `doSomething: '&'` `doSomething: '='` and remove the parentheses for the node and leaf markup.

Comment: could you add the code that you tried and isn't working

Comment: A codepen would be very useful here. Everything you've described should work.

Comment: Added a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7L4Kd3rhJXoGlrHzecHf?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: This may or may not actually work...**

It would appear as though when you call a function that was provided with the `&` operator that you are not calling the function directly, but rather calling a function which uses its argument as a sort of context for the expression. The following works:

`app.js`:

```
const appController = ($scope, data) => {
  $scope.doSomething = value => console.log(value);
};
```

`app.html`:

```
<div>
  <node
    do-something="doSomething(value)"
  ></node>
</div>
```

`node.js`:

```
app.component('node', {
  // ...
  bindings: {
    doSomething: '&',
  },
});
```

`node.html`:

```
<div>
  <leaf
    do-something="$ctrl.doSomething({ value: value })"
  ></leaf>
</div>
```

`leaf.js`:

```
app.component('leaf', {
  // ...
  bindings: {
    doSomething: '&',
  },
});
```

`leaf.html`:

```
<div ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething({ value: someVar })"></div>
```

Comment: KPthunder, want to add a working Plunkr and accept this answer for other?

Comment: Turns out it doesn't actually work the way I thought it did. I come from a React background and I was trying to shoehorn a flux architecture in an Angular project but I wound up doing something different.